# Conda install takes forever (stuck as SAT solver)

Tags: python, miniconda

How can I fix problem with conda installer, which takes forever solving huge SAT problems (why do we need to solve them?):

```
DEBUG conda.common.logic:_run_sat(734): Invoking SAT with clause count: 9661561
DEBUG conda.common.logic:_run_sat(734): Invoking SAT with clause count: 5164645
DEBUG conda.common.logic:_run_sat(734): Invoking SAT with clause count: 2751948
DEBUG conda.common.logic:_run_sat(734): Invoking SAT with clause count: 1518175
DEBUG conda.common.logic:_run_sat(734): Invoking SAT with clause count: 964848
DEBUG conda.common.logic:_run_sat(734): Invoking SAT with clause count: 1249154
DEBUG conda.common.logic:_run_sat(734): Invoking SAT with clause count: 1105581
```

Waited more then half of a hour, what else can I do rather then reinstall this?

Comment: `why do we need to solve them?` SAT in conda is used as underlying solver to satisfy dependencies

Comment: the real solution is to create a bat/sh script that reinstates your current enviroments, and wipe/reinstall anaconda every 3 months or so

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
conda update -n base -c defaults conda
```

Answer (score 9):

`conda` can run into endless loops when trying to figure out a way to satisfy all the dependencies of the packages that are installed, along with the changes you want to apply. I've read somewhere that if it hasn't found a solution within two minutes, there's not much point in waiting any longer.

In general, you overcome such situations by being more specific about what you want. For example, specify exact versions instead of just package names. If you don't need conda-forge, avoid that channel, because it brings in a lot of metadata that the SAT resolver will try to consider.

Here's a huge blog article from Anaconda with ways to improve performance:
    https://www.anaconda.com/understanding-and-improving-condas-performance/

Answer (score 5):

I fixed the issue by modifying ~/.condarc

In other words, conda-forge is too slow, so make the defaults first priority for solver

by changing this:

```
auto_activate_base: false
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
channel_priority: strict
allow_conda_downgrades: true
```

to this:

```
auto_activate_base: false
channels:
  - defaults
  - conda-forge
channel_priority: strict
allow_conda_downgrades: true
```

Answer (score 0):

Just my two cents for anyone coming to this 4 years later: use the libmamba solver and save your time. It's blazing fast.

Comment: It's not clear how to use it, please give some details.

Comment: Pretty much as per the instructions here. https://www.anaconda.com/blog/conda-is-fast-now Update your conda, install the libmamba solver, and set that as your default solver. Just a few commands.